# How is PowerPoint Turing complete?

Tags: computability, turing-completeness

From my understanding, Turing complete means that the program or machine can complete any computation that a Turing machine can complete, which to me means any computation. So how can something like HTML or PowerPoint be Turing complete?

Comment: How says they are?

Comment: I don't think this question is ontopic: we are not interested in the specific capabilities of PowerPoint. Community votes, please!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some system is Turing complete if you can simulate every Turing machine inside of it. Powerpoint is Turing complete because its animation features can be used to simulate a Turing machine. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNjxe8ShM-8) explains the proof for Powerpoint. You can read the proceedings from the [2017 SIGBOVIK](http://sigbovik.org/2017/proceedings.pdf) for a written explanation.

Comment: Could you explain more what it means to be a Turing machine? I thought that a Turing machine means any computation

Comment: A Turing machine is an abstract machine that looks a lot like a computer from ca 1930. [Check Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_machine)